# How do I use Scrapy to crawl within pages?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Python and Scrapy for this question.

I am attempting to crawl webpage **A**, which contains a list of links to webpages **B1, B2, B3, ...** Each **B** page contains a link to another page, **C1, C2, C3, ...**, which contains an image.

So, using Scrapy, the idea in pseudo-code is:

```
links = getlinks(A)
for link in links:
    B = getpage(link)
    C = getpage(B)
    image = getimage(C)
```

However, I am running into a problem when trying to parse more than one page in Scrapy. Here is my code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = hxs.select('...')

    items = []
    for link in links:
        item = CustomItem()
        item['name'] = link.select('...')
        # TODO: Somehow I need to go two pages deep and extract an image.
        item['image'] = ....
```

How would I go about doing this?

(Note: My question is similar to [Using multiple spiders at in the project in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886940/using-multiple-spiders-at-in-the-project-in-scrapy) but I am unsure how to "return" values from Scrapy's Request objects.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In scrapy the parse method needs to return a new Request if you need to issue more requests (use`yield` as scrapy works well with generators). Inside this request you can set a callback to the desired function (to be recursive just pass `parse` again). Thats the way to crawl into pages.

You can check [this recursive crawler](https://github.com/bcap/wikipedia-music/blob/master/crawler/crawler/spiders/music_info_spider.py) as example

Following your example, the change would be something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    b_pages_links = getlinks(A)
    for link in b_pages_links:
        yield Request(link, callback = self.visit_b_page)

def visit_b_page(self, response):
    url_of_c_page = ...
    yield Request(url_of_c_page, callback = self.visit_c_page)

def visit_c_page(self, response):
    url_of_image = ...
    yield Request(url_of_image, callback = self.get_image)

def get_image(self, response):
    item = CustomItem()
    item['name'] = ... # get image name
    item['image'] = ... # get image data
    yield item
```

Also check the [scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/) and [these random code snippets](http://snipplr.com/all/tags/scrapy/). They can help a lot :)

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome. If I wanted to create the `CustomItem` in the  `parse` method, would I pass it using the meta property?

Comment: Also, I want to return a list of items (`items = []`). How would I use the above and then, upon its completion, append the item to the list?

Comment: The spider only function is to visit a page, extract and return the data (the final `yield item`). To aggregate data, like putting all the items in a list, you need to create a function in the `pipelines` module (this is a convention only). [This example pipeline](https://github.com/bcap/wikipedia-music/blob/master/crawler/crawler/pipelines.py) creates a dot file based on all the music genres that were crawled

Comment: Also remember to declare your pipeline function in the `settings.py`, like in [here](https://github.com/bcap/wikipedia-music/blob/master/crawler/crawler/settings.py)

Comment: And to solve the problem in creating the item in the parse and completing it in another functions, you can indeed use meta. This is documented [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions)

Comment: You don't need to append the requests to a list. If there are more than one Item to return, just yield each of them in a for loop.

Comment: @BrunoPolaco, what if the A page and B pages have some items I want to scrap too? How to set the callback in that case?